# What is difference in syntax between these two GAP commands?

Tags: group-theory, gap

In Gap System,

1.

```
g:=Group( [[1,1],[0,1]] );;
```

2.

```
g:=[[1,1],[0,1]];;
```

As I know Group is generally a permutation group, however, finite group is also a group then it makes me confusing. As I know, finite group is a matrix, how can it be a group or permutation group?

Comment: Why do you think that last one defines any sort of group at all? It defines a list of lists (which in some contexts will be interpreted as a matrix by GAP).

Comment: "As i know, finite group is a matrix" What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[1,1],[0,1]]` is typically interpreted as a $2 \times 2$ matrix in GAP.  To illustrate, matrix multiplication `*` is defined: `[[1,1],[0,1]]*[[1,1],[0,1]]` returns `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 0, 1 ] ]`. This object can also be treated as a list of lists.

`Group( [[1,1],[0,1]] )` is the (infinite) group generated by this matrix under multiplication.  The size of the group is given by `Size(g)` which returns `infinity`.  In this case, `[[1,1],[0,1]]` is a generator of the group.

All groups are "structurally equivalent" to some permutation group (via [Cayley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)), but this is up to isomorphism; groups can be defined with arbitrary underlying sets (that may not involve permutations).  We tend to prefer to choose easy-to-work-with sets, such as sets of integers, matrices or permutations.

If by "finite group is a matrix" you mean finite groups have finite [Cayley tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table), then this is true.  Once you have an isomorphism between the group and a permutation group, you can relabel the elements of the Cayley table as permutations.  It's not usually a useful thing to do, however.

Comment: does you mean that [[1,1],[0,1]] is a cayley table? if so, is it possible to input a cayley table and find back permutation group

Comment: No it's not.  A Cayley table (or multiplication table) it's just a way of tabulating the results of using the group binary operation.  Different binary operations give different groups, and thus different Cayley tables, but `[[1,1],[0,1]]` cannot be one, since it would not satisfy the cancellation property.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in **syntax** is approximately the same like between, say,

```
a:=Sin(0.0);
```

and

```
a:=0.0;
```

In the latter, one constructs an object (zero in floating-point representation) and assigns it to a variable. In the former, one constructs an object, applies a function to the constructed object and then assigns the result to a variable.

In your example, the object is a list of two lists of length two (which GAP treats as a matrix), and the function returns a cyclic group generated by this object. These group contains this matrix and all its powers, and this is why it is infinite.

Regarding the last paragraph of the question: the GAP F.A.Q. answers the question ["Which skills do I need to use GAP?"](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#1.3) and it mentions among others *the necessary knowledge of the part of mathematics you would like to work on*. It would be really hard to proceed with learning GAP otherwise, and I very much recommend to find and read some introductory group theory textbook. Just learning group theory by reading the GAP manual is not sufficient, since it is not written for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In 2, your g is a 2 element list of two element lists. You can (and your software might) consider this a $2\times 2$ matrix. In 1 you apply an operator Group to this object. You don't specify what software you are using, but it presumably returns the group generated by g in some format.

Comment: search keyword is gap, i updated question to indicate this is gap system